# Change pickers dialog tint/colors/theme in Android

Tags: android, android-theme, picker, datepickerdialog

I need to know how to change the color of the pickers dialog (TimePickerDialog and DatePickerDialog)

I am using Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.

Here is the code where I build the dialog:

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

I know there's another constructor that receives a Theme, but that causes the Dialog to be the only element being show in the whole screen. I'll add a ss of the elements I want to handle.

[image: Current dialog]

I need the colors of the dividers to be purple. And the color of the font in the header to be purple as well.

Next is a ss of a Nexus 5 which has a larger area of a color I do not want

[image: Nexus five theme]

As you can see the theme is more prominent and I need to customize it. How can this be achieve?

Thanks guys. If you need any more info to help me I'll provide anything, I really need to manage the theme of these dialog.

The following image is a actual ss of the whole screen when I use this constructor:

```
DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), 
            android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_NoActionBar,
            this,
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

[image]

Comment: You should use a Dialog theme Like Theme.Light.dialog
instead of Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar(this supposed to be a full screen)